# Accept XPATH 2.0 expression

Tags: xtext, xpath-2.0

I want the users of a `xtext` DSL to be able to enter a XPATH 2.0 expression.

What would be the prefered way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an existing openly available Xtext grammar for XPath (or XQuery or XSLT) so you will probably have to write your own grammar.

The details depend very much on your use case (e.g. should the user only be able to enter XPaths conforming to a given XSD etc. or should they be allowed to use any tag names), so it is hard to give specific answers to such a generic question. I guess you are already aware of the Xtext documentation, but for reference: http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/index.html

Depending on your requirements, the Eclipse MDT XSD library might be useful: https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/modeling.mdt.xsd